# How to search for items in list control and higlight a row

Tags: visual-c++

I am coding a program which need to highlight an item in list control when dialog box creates.
I am creating a list control in dialog box in via resource not CreateWindow() or CreateWindowEx().

I want to know that how can I highlight a row and how can I search in?
For example is a user types "Demo" in edit box then how can I search for "Demo" in list control and highlight it?

I need help in Win32 API with C

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

1, For search string in listbox control you can send message [LB_FINDSTRING](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775187%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [LB_FINDSTRINGEXACT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775189%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Both return zero based index of item in listbox which match your string

2, by "highlist" item, you probably mean select this item.
There is message [LB_SETSEL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761352%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which can by used to set selection state

Comment: Please be more specific. I am a newbie in WinAPI programming.